# Strange Exception executing built Android app on Android devices

Tags: android, codenameone, runtimeexception, android-handler

I get a strange crash of my Android App when I try to execute it on an Android device.If I try to execute my App I get this error:

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.remaxer.codenameone.edmtuner/com.remaxer.codenameone.edmtuner.EdmTunerStub}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.codename1.j.o com.codename1.impl.a.z()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.codename1.j.o com.codename1.impl.a.z()' on a null object reference
at com.codename1.j.k.x(Display.java:2172)
at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(CodenameOneActivity.java:358)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2921)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:599)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:973)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:305)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doPendingInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:947)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2185)
at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1082)
at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1027)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1175)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
... 10 more
```

Then the application crashes and when I open it again, the error disappears.
Then waiting about 1 hour the error rises again.

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Kindly provide full stacktrace, It's hard to figure out what line is throwing the exception.

Comment: Posted the full stack trace on pastebin

Comment: This seems like a codenameone android framework bug, which was fixed already.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a codename one android framework bug, which was fixed already in the git repository

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NullPointerException` somewhere in your code. Might be somewhere around the `onCreateOptionsMenu` lifecycle method in an `Activity` or `Fragment`. You can only track this down using the "mapping.txt" file generated by Proguard.

If you're looking for this file, it should be in your application module's directory in: `build/outputs/proguard/release/mapping.txt`

Keep in mind that if you have ProGuard enabled, every time you create a build the mapping can change.

It seems like you have ProGuard enabled when you create the build.
If you'd like to disable ProGuard and track the issue down easier, please update the `minifyEnabled` property in your app's Gradle file. This has to be set to false. Something like:

```
android {
    ....
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
}
```